# Hash Table Implementation Using An Array of Linked Lists

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, hashtable

This question has been bugging me for quite a long time and today I've read a detailed article related to hash tables. Without checking any **implementation examples** I wanted to give a shot for writing a Hash Table from scratch.

The **seperate chaining** method gave me the idea of implementing the hash table. Anyone who has experience on data structures might regard this question as a joke but i'm a beginner and without diving straight at the code I wanted to discuss my implementations efficiency. Would it be efficient or any other fundamental ideas could be preferred than this?

Comment: separate chaining works well IF you have a GOOD hash algorithm, then there will be few collisions and each chain is small.

Comment: So linear probing would be significantly better or doesn't create much difference?

Comment: There are trade offs for both approaches. In the worst case separate chaining turns into an `LinkedList` and linear probing requires recalculating the hash until you check every cell and they both are `O(n)`. The real key to whether a `HashTable` is implemented well is the Hash Algorithm used (and the size of the structure) as that determines how many collisions there will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think for starters you can also peek into the source (or documentations) of some hash maps implemented in boost libraries. It is called unordered_map. [(link is  here)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html)

As long as you don't know about these implementations and want to use a hash and you are annoyed because it is not in STL, you are intrigued to write your own fast datastore.
But now implementing hash-maps are so much out of the game that C++11 has unordered_map in its STL. You'll see there are plenty of more interesting stuff out there.

Note: separate chaining is called bucket hash. In fact, **boost uses bucket hash**, see [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered/buckets.html). Maybe you could rather look up some performance comparisons. Chances are those who do perf's will write good enough implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Using closed addressing, another alternative is to use a self balancing binary search tree, e.g. red-black tree/std::map or heap tree, for the inner data structure, or even another hash map with different hashing algorithm.

Using [open addressing](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing), another alternative to linear probing are quadratic probing and [double hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing); there are also less commonly used strategies such as cuckoo hashing, hopscotch hashing, etc.

The key points of implementing hash table is choosing the right hashing algorithm, resizing strategy (load factor), and collision resolution strategy. The best strategy is highly dependant on the type of workload that you're expecting as there are tradeoffs for each approach.